# how to "center" dashed lines of Path?

Tags: swiftui

I create a grid system as a `Shape`:

```
struct StrokeGrid: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    
        var path = Path()
    
        let topLeft = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY)
        let topCenter = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY)
        let topRight = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY)
        let leftCenter = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.midY)
        let rightCenter = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.midY)
        let bottomLeft = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY)
        let bottomCenter = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.maxY)
        let bottomRight = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY)
    
        path.move(to: topLeft)
        path.addLine(to: bottomRight)
        path.move(to: topCenter)
        path.addLine(to: bottomCenter)
        path.move(to: topRight)
        path.addLine(to: bottomLeft)
        path.move(to: leftCenter)
        path.addLine(to: rightCenter)
    
        return path
    }
}
```

In my View I use it this way:

```
struct GridView: View {
    var body: some View {
    
        ZStack(){
            Color.gray.opacity(0.1)
            StrokeGrid()
                .stroke(Color.gray.opacity(0.5), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 3, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .bevel, dash: [10]))
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately SwiftUI doesn't center the dashed lines automatically so that a dash line is in the center of the line itself. Is there any parameter to do this or do I have to calculate the "ideal" dash size? If so, what is the math behind it? My goal is to get a grid system with dashed lines that create a "star"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to draw 8 different lines to the center.

---

```
struct StrokeGrid: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    
        var path = Path()
    
        let topLeft = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY)
        
        
        let topCenter = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY)
        
        let topRight = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY)
        
        let leftCenter = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.midY)
        
        let rightCenter = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.midY)
        
        let bottomLeft = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY)
        
        let bottomCenter = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.maxY)
        
        let bottomRight = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY)
        
        let center = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
        
        path.move(to: topLeft)
        path.addLine(to: center)
        path.move(to: center)
        path.closeSubpath()
        path.addLine(to: bottomLeft)
        
        path.move(to: topRight)
        path.closeSubpath()
        path.addLine(to: center)
        path.move(to: center)
        path.closeSubpath()
        path.addLine(to: bottomRight)
        
        
        path.move(to: rightCenter)
        path.addLine(to: center)
        path.move(to: center)
        path.closeSubpath()
        path.addLine(to: leftCenter)
        
        path.move(to: topCenter)
        path.addLine(to: center)
        path.move(to: center)
        path.closeSubpath()
        path.addLine(to: bottomCenter)
        
        
    
        return path
    }
}
```